# Exit code.InteractiveConsole().interact() without exiting main program

Tags: python, interactive

I have a Python program that needs to embed the Python Interactive Console.

I'm currently using `InteractiveConsole` from `code` module:

`code.InteractiveConsole().interact()`

However if I type `exit()` in the console, the whole program is exited.

How can I exit the interactive console without exiting the main program?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this. https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/30i599/gracefully_break_out_of_codeinteractiveconsole/

Comment: @PhillipMartin Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @PhillipMartin I managed to do it after reading his link: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/30i599/gracefully_break_out_of_codeinteractiveconsole/

```
def console_exit():
    raise SystemExit

try:
    code.InteractiveConsole(locals={"exit": console_exit}).interact()
except SystemExit:
    pass

# Continue doing stuff
```

This lets `exit` in the console raise `SystemExit` only, without changing other things (like manipulating stdin etc.), and intercepts it at the outer program.

Btw, since I don't need to inherit `code.InteractiveConsole` I should use `code.interact(...)` instead.